# How to give “Network Service” permissions on another non-domain computer?

Tags: postgresql, file-sharing, ntfs, hosts

I have PostgreSQL running on a Win10 Pro box (called DBServer) on my local network. I need to allow it to read files on my Dev computer (also Win10 Pro) on the same network so it can import files.

PostgreSQL runs as Network Service so I need to somehow allow Dev access to DBServer's Network Service. My research indicates that you can do this by adding permissions to `Domain/DbServer$`. Fine, but I am not on a domain.

I tried adding a domain to Dev's hosts file (`10.0.0.188    newdbserver.com`) and adding permissions for `newdbserver.com/DbServer$` but that name is not found.

Seems like I am so close, yet so far away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that this can be done for non-domain machines. You can have PostgreSQL run as a named account on DBSERVER, and create an account with the same name and password on DEV.

HOSTS files are for DNS resolution; a DNS domain is (in this context) not the same thing as an AD domain, so that is barking up the wrong tree unfortunately.